# Subquery returning more than 1 value in cursor in trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, cursor, subquery

So this is for a school assignment so I have to use the trigger with a cursor. I've been beating my head against this for far too long and haven't found anything useful. So I have table book with

```
[BOOK_CODE]
[TITLE]
[PUBLISHER_CODE]
[TYPE]
[PRICE]
[PAPERBACK]
```

what I would like is when paperback switches from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 it will double or halve the price. So here is the trigger I have:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[paper2Hard]
on [dbo].[BOOK]
after update
as
declare @done int;
declare @the_books varchar(255);
declare @b_code varchar(4)

/*This is suppose to grab all the rows that have had a change from 0 to 1 */

declare p2h cursor for 
select i.price from inserted i, deleted d 
where i.paperback > d.paperback;
```

/*Syntactic stuff i don't quite understand */

```
open p2h
```

/*This is suppose to get one row at a time and stick it into the loop*/

```
fetch p2h into @the_books
begin 
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 

    /* This is suppose to get the book_code from the current row */

set @b_code = (select book_code from deleted)

    /*Then double the price while matching book_code to book_code */ 

update book 
set price = (price*2)
where book.book_code = @b_code

    /*Then go to the next one and keep doing it until they are all done*/

fetch next from p2h into @the_books 
end
close p2h
end
```

Now it works for single row queries but when I try to do a multirow query (set paperback = 1 where book_code = x or book_code = y) it says: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

I don't understand what its referring to and would appreciate any help if you can point me in the right direction here.

Well I finally got it to work and I understand what I was doing wrong.

```
declare @the_book varchar(4);

declare p2h cursor for 
select i.book_code from inserted i, deleted d 
where i.paperback > d.paperback;
open p2h
fetch p2h into @the_book

begin 
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 
update book
set price = (price*2)
where book_code=@the_book
fetch next from p2h into @the_book 
end
```

I guess the biggest problem was a fundamental misunderstanding of what cursors are/how they work. So in the interest of future generations who, like I, have a difficult time deciphering the technobabble of the documentation.

When you declare the name of the cursor and run the select statement it acts like an array. You can then store the values in the array one by one using the fetch into @var Thus allowing you to use those values. So I guess the normal use of the select statement is to get the primary key/s of the records you need to change.

Comment: The `JOIN` condition between your tables doesn't make much sense to me. What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: Do you have to use cursor for this? It can be done easily without any cursor

Comment: @M.Ali I would say yes, since the question starts with: *So this is for a school assignment so I have to use the trigger with a cursor*

Comment: If you are in school you need to stop immediately using implicit joins, they are a sql antipattern and a very poor prgoramming technique. Inyour case I can't believe you really want that particular join result. Of course I have no respect for a teacher that would want you to use a cursor in a trigger either, this is something that should never happen.

Comment: Yea thats why I was asking OP does the tutor want OP to use cursor or is it just a Trigger test.

Comment: The primary key is book_code. It worked fine for my trigger which was basically that without the extra cursor stuff. For some reason i didn't keep a copy of my previous trigger. And yes we specifically have to have a cursor to allow the trigger that we previously designed work for multiple rows. 
The join that I had (that worked before, I don't really know what is going on here anymore) just grabbed the book code from deleted and matched book code from inserted to check if paperback was changed. Then use that book code to change the price.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
set @b_code = (select book_code from deleted)
```

It is never correct to set the results of the inserted or deleted tables to a scalar variable  as they can contain mulitple rows. SQL Server trigger do not run row by row. You need to use a join an ot a variable.

You may have to learn this for class, but in real life you should not consider using a cursor ever in a trigger and only very rarely elsewhere.